# Fibonacci series have some run time error

Tags: c

[enter image description here][1][here when I take `if(series==0) return 0;` in Fibonacci definition function before `if(series==1) return 1;` then Fibonacci series are printing successfully but when I remove this line and then compile my program it takes term inout and then show a error message like

> **Fibonacci.exe has stop working**
>   but when I add that line program executing successfully. what happening that.
>   somebody will tell me
>   ][2]
>   here's my code :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int fibonacci(int);  // declaration of fibonacci function.

int main(){
    int input_num,i,series=1;
    printf("Enter the term you want to print fibonacci series : ");
    scanf("%d", &input_num);

    printf("\n Fibonacci Series Are : ");

    for(i=0; i<input_num; i++){
        printf("%d,", fibonacci(series));
        series++;
    }

    return 0;
}

//defination of fibonacci function
int fibonacci(int series){


    if(series==1) return 1;

    return(fibonacci(series-1)+fibonacci(series-2));

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, to help you get better responses, could you please copy the code and place it in a code block within your question?

Comment: how? can you see my program -Eugene Sh

Comment: Consider what happens when you call `fibonacci(0)` without the line `if (series==0) return 0;`. Does the function recurse? If so, what arguments are passed to the recursive calls? When does the recursion stop? Also, it's oddly appropriate that you asked this question on StackOverflow.

Comment: nope not right now -Eugene Sh

Comment: -Mike Holt why dont you check my code on your compiler and try to do what I asked. I have developed this code on DevC++ ide.

Comment: @AshokPandey I don't need to check your code on my compiler to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Walk through your code.  Without that line, what happens when you call fibonacci(2)?  What about when you include it?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (series==1) return 1;
```

This has the problem that you also call the function with `series-2` so it can get smaller than one. Replace with:

```
if (series<=1) return 1;
```

See also "Defensive programming"

Comment: Yes it is working properly now. thanks @Paul Ogilvie for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Each recursive function needed some kind of base condition to converge.
In the Fibonacci program, the function is called recursively two times `fibonacci(n-1)` and `fibonacci(n-2)`. Here two base case is possible that's why you have to check for both 0 and 1.

example:      fibonacci(3) ==> fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(2)
              fibonacci(2) ==> fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)

```
if(series==0) return 0;
else if(series==1) return 1;
else return(fibonacci(series-1)+fibonacci(series-2));
```